# ¿ cómo corresponder el color de cada categoría consu label en un gráfico de dispersión?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Estoy realizando un scatter plot donde relaciono las valoraciones de  libros con su precio, en función del tipo. El tipo, como es una variable categórica, he utilizado `LabelEncoder()` para asignarle un valor a cada categoría. Luego, al representar el gráfico se ejecuta correctamente, pero el problema viene a la hora de poner la leyenda, pues al ponerla no se asocia cada color del gráfico con el tipo de libro.

Código utilizado:

```
for y, c in zip(data['Type'].unique(), book_type):
    plt.scatter(data["Rating"], data['Price'], c=book_type, label=y)

plt.xlabel('Valoraciones')
plt.ylabel('Precio')
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

Adjunto imagen para que se vea el gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Véase como la variable book_type contiene los valores de cada tipo de libro, data['Rating'] son las valoraciones de los libros y data['Price'] es el precio.

Como ven, hay varios comentarios en el código porque he estado probando varias formas de hacerlo sin éxito. No consigo que la leyenda tenga los colores del gráfico.

Adjunto un print sobre los datos y un print sobre la variable 'book_type':

data

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

book_type:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede ver que book_type tiene valores, los cuales pertenecen cada uno a cada una de las categorías de data['Type'].

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar lo agradecería mucho.

Un saludo.

Comment: Has probado de quitar el argumento "c=book_type" ?

Comment: Es que si lo quito en el gráfico no sale cada punto de un color disitinto en función del tipo de libro.

Comment: Cuando haces c=book_type, book_type deveria ser un color. Pero fijate, en el bucle estas iterando sobre diferentes book_type con "c". Entonces debarias poner c=c (te sugiero que iteres con otra letra para no confundir)

Comment: La cosa es que ya he probado hacer eso y me salta el siguiente mensaje de error:  
" 'c' argument has 1 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 271."   Cosa que no entiendo porque book_type no solo tiene un argumento. Entonces no sé qué puede estar pasando ahí...

Comment: Puedes hacer un print(data) print(book_type) para entender la estuctra de los datos y subir el resultado a la pregunta?

Comment: Sin problema, la acabo de subir!

Comment: Por favor sube el código en formato código, por otro lado se agradecería que agregaras un ejemplo verfícable que reproduzca el problema, recomiendo leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar .plot() propio de Pandas:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1970)

num = 20
x, y = np.random.random((2, num))
labels = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], num)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y, label=labels))

groups = df.groupby('label')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(0.05)
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.x, group.y, marker='o', linestyle='', ms=12, label=name)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Genial! He conseguido hacer el gráfico y la leyenda concuerda con este. Muchas gracias!